# PHP is not update page from formdata

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, form-data

My goal is to get the value of a selector on 1 page. I want to
have a user select a year and update the page when selected a year.
Without the `$_GET` function.

I will demonstrate it with steps, to understand it a bit more.

- **Step 1:** This is the select element that the user is going to press on a year [The
  selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWdR0.png)
- **Step 2:** There should be an `echo` what the user has selected. For example; I choose 2019 > there should be a `echo` somewhere which prints `2019`.

This is `getData.php`

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('php://input');

echo json_decode($_POST["year"]);

echo $_POST["year"];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="../js/chartSelector.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <select name="jaarKiezer" id="jaarKiezer" onchange="changeData()">
    <option selected disabled>Choose a year</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2021">2021</option>
  </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is `chartSelector.js`

```
console.log("connected with js");
function changeData() {
    let yearJS = document.getElementById("jaarKiezer").value;
    console.log("changed to " + yearJS);
    getData(yearJS);
}

function getData(yearJS) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("year", yearJS);
    fetch("../getData.php", {
        "body": formData,
        "method": "POST"
    }).catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

In the
network tab on preview you see its [working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aJhx.png). The problem comes when I want to post the form data into php, on the 'live' page
nothing happens. Only 2 errors from `getData.php`: `Undefined array key "year"`.

Some images to understand it a bit more:

- The network tab itself: [Network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsmoD.png)
- The payload: [Payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjGQC.png)
- The preview: [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aJhx.png)

I've tried:

- AJAX
- Using the `JSON.stringify(formData)` function.
- Using Headers *(Like: `header(Content-Type: application/json)`)*.

*Note: I'm using ***php server*** from the vscode extensions*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two distinct problems here.

## A fundamental misunderstanding of how Ajax works

The browser makes an HTTP request. It gets an HTML document and renders it in the viewport.

The page contains some JavaScript which tells it to make a new HTTP request. The response is returned to JavaScript for further processing.

You don't do any further processing so the only effect you see is in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools.

The request **does not** travel back in time, replace the previous request for the page to display, and change the page displayed.

If you want to replace the entire page with a new one: Use a regular form submission. Do not use Ajax.

If you want to do something with the response to the Ajax request, then you need to write JavaScript that does that something.

```
async function getData(yearJS) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("year", yearJS);
    try { 
        const response = await fetch("../getData.php", {
            "body": formData,
            "method": "POST"
        });
        const html = await response.text();
        console.log(html); // Do something with the HTML more useful than logging it. 
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

## You aren't dealing with JSON

`FormData` objects are converted into multipart form data request bodies, **not** JSON.

Remove:

> ```
> echo file_get_contents('php://input');
>
> echo json_decode($_POST["year"]);
> ```

PHP will parse multipart form data request bodies and populate `$_POST` and `$_FILES` with the contents automatically.

Comment: You should add that the script shouldn't return an entire HTML page. It should just return the HTML that should be inserted into the existing page. Or it should return JSON and the JavaScript can create DOM elements from that.